# how to replace numbers in string of python into consecutive numbers and same new number for repetitions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to modify numbers in a file that begins from any number (7 in this case) to begin from 1 and goes consecutively. But if the number in next line is same, it should not print new consecutive number, instead it should give same new number.

I will be able to access all these numbers based on column position. The numbers in which I am interested are only in 5th and 6th column.

To be more clear

My input file has:

YYY 7

YYY 7

YYY 7

YYY 8

YYY 8

YYY 9

YYY 9

YYY 9

YYY 11

YYY 11

I want output like:

YYY 1

YYY 1

YYY 1

YYY 2

YYY 2

YYY 3

YYY 3

YYY 3

YYY 4

YYY 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick! there might be a better way to do this.

Hope this helps! cheers!

```
def main():
    mapping={}
    counter=0
    with open("./input.txt") as f, open("./output.txt","w") as output:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line=line.replace("\n","")
            parts= line.split(" ")
            x=parts[0]
            y=parts[1]
            if y not in mapping:
                counter+=1
                mapping[y]=counter

            output.write("{} {}".format(x,mapping[y]))
            print(("{} {}".format(x,mapping[y])))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) based trick to get contiguous `1`-based "indexes":

```
 from collections import defaultdict

 ind = defaultdict(lambda: len(ind) + 1)
 for row in data:
     row[4] = ind[row[4]]
```

This will create a consistent mapping of old values to new values with new values from `[1..n]`.